# android proguard in debug builds?

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-debug

I have an android app, which supports android >= 4.
In debug compilation it has > 65k methods, thus it is multidex.
In release, I use proguard, and it has 38k methods, and is not multidex.
How would I develop an app, which in debug mode can crash, just beacuse it is over 65k methods?

I thing I can use proguard in debug builds too, but didn't see anyone doing it + it would take much more time on compilation, using proguard
How would you handle this situation?

PS
my app.gradle looks like this (dependency's section):

```
        compile project(':signalr-client-sdk-android')
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
        compile "com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:${UNIVERSAL_IMAGE_LOADER}"
        compile "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:${CIRCLE_IMAGE_VER}"
        compile "com.pixplicity.multiviewpager:library:${MULTIVIEW_PAGER_VER}"
        compile "com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:${ACTIVE_ANDROID_VER}"
        compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:${OKHTTP_VER}"
        compile "com.rockerhieu.emojicon:library:${EMOJI_VERSION}"
        compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:${FACEBOOK_SDK_VER}"
        compile "com.makeramen:roundedimageview:${ROUNDED_IMAGEVIEW_VER}"
        compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.0@aar'

        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${GSM_VER}"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${ANALITICS_VER}"

        compile "com.flurry.android:analytics:${FLURRY_VER}"

        compile 'com.supersonic.sdk:mediationsdk:6.3.6@jar'

        //effects apng tool
        compile project(':android_api')
        compile project(':flingCards')

        compile files('libs/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar')
```

And I use all of this libs

Comment: Post your multidex code, i think you have only make multidex true in gradle.

Comment: I do not want to make app multidex! It will act flacky, my app for sure shoud stay not multidex

Comment: If you dont want to make application as multidex then remove some jar files which are not useful for the application and use it. if you are using play services then use particular play service dependency in the gradle.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki , I can not remove any jars, or libs, I use them all. About play services I know. Please tell me other options, if any exist

Comment: Let me know what you are using in play service, GCM or any other library.

Comment: you are using the play service for individual functionality only, and from your code I can only say that there is no other way for reducing method no in the project. You have to create multidex file for debug or else for all the debug you need to use proguard which is not a recommended solution. Better you create multidex file and it will not give you any performance issue.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki Thanks for help. really, i can use multidex file for debug flavor. But there could occure crashes, which not exist in release. Android <5 sucks..

Answer (score 5):

I use proguard in debug builds. Usualy my build.gradle looks like this:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
    }
}
```

Notice the different proguard file (proguard-rules-debug.pro) for debug which has -dontobfuscate option added.

The time it takes to compile it with proguard is about 5-10% longer which is acceptable to me. I'm not using instant run so I don't know how it's affected by this.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ProGuard in debug too. Add this to your `buildTypes`:

```
    debug {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        jniDebuggable true
    }
```

Inside your app `build.gradle`

Comment: I am doing this way now. But comilation takes much more time, and that is a problem

Comment: So, I think you only have a few options, to slow compile with Proguard, not to compile or try if with multidex it doesn't take so long. There aren't more options.

Comment: Or maybe you could try to reduce your libraries by changing them. I see you have an "Universal image loader"  and a "circle image view" library, if i am not wrong you can change them with Glide.

Comment: I love UIL too much to refuse from it. Ant it takes not too many methids, less than 2k. circle image view takes only 200 methods

Comment: You must make a decision : )      Here you have the official docs: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html.

Comment: `debuggable` flag is only for NDK builds.  Why are you using it?

Comment: Only for NDK? Where did you read that? From the official docs (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html): "This allows you to debug the app on secure Android devices and configures APK signing with a generic debug keystore."

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez Interesting.  What is the consequence of omitting this `debuggable` flag?  I mean, does it make any difference?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If i'm not wrong this flag is set to true by default in debug builds so it isn't needed. But I usually add it anyway.